# Invalid Function Elisp

Tags: elisp

I have the following code:

```
(defun rember
    (lambda (a lat)
      (cond
       ((null lat) '())
       (else (cond
              ((eq (car lat) a) (cdr lat))
               (else (rember a
                             (cdr lat))))))))
(rember 2 '(4 5 6 7))
```

When I run this using `C-x C-e`, I get the following error:

```
Invalid function: (lambda (lambda (a lat) (cond ((null lat) (quote nil)) (else (cond\
 ((eq (car lat) a) (cdr lat)) (else (rember a (cdr lat))))))) nil)
```

I don't know why. Can someone help?

Comment: Without any indication of what this is supposed to do, we can only speculate. `(defun rember
    (lambda (a lat) ...))` should probably be `(defun rember (a lat) ...)`

Comment: `(defun rember (...))` is a function called `rember` which takes an argument list `...` and returns nil.  In your case the argument list is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mixing up Lisp and Scheme syntax for defining functions.  In Lisp, as you're using `defun` instead of `defvar`, it is already implied that you're defining a function, so you don't need to wrap the code in `lambda`:

```
(defun rember (a lat)
  (cond
   ((null lat) '())
   (else (cond
          ((eq (car lat) a) (cdr lat))
          (else (rember a
                        (cdr lat)))))))
```

(Next you'll find that `else` is not treated specially inside `cond` in Emacs Lisp, so you'll need to use `t` instead.)

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense.